# How to set preference for one of duplicating sections in man pages?

Tags: linux, manpage

I see the following question every time I open man pages for git commands:

```
-> man git-log
Man: find all matching manual pages
 * git-log (1)
   git-log (1+)
Man: What manual page do you want?
```

After that I have to wait till the first section is opened automatically or choose it manually.

The question is raised because of two versions of git and its man pages installed on my work host (where I am an ordinary user without administrative privileges):

```
-> man --where --all git-log
/app/vbuild/SLED11-x86_64/git/2.14.1/man/man1/git-log.1
/usr/share/man/man1/git-log.1.gz

-> echo $MANPATH
/app/vbuild/SLED11-x86_64/git/2.14.1/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/man

-> man --version
man 2.5.2
```

When I remove the first path from MANPATH, the older version of git man pages is opened without any questions. If I remove '/usr/share/man', the newer version is opened automatically but I loose access to pages for other (non-git) commands. Neither of these options is suitable for me.

Can I set preference for one of duplicating sections while keeping others (not duplicating) available as well?

**Update:**

I have found (thanks to David C. Rankin and a mistake I made through lack of attention) that man's option `-c` helps to get the desired effect. It is described as follows in the man page for man:

```
-c, --catman
      This option is not for general use and should only be used by the catman program.
```

So, it is still not clear what the cause of the problem is, why and how the option helps and if it is correct to use it in this way.

I tried to debug man by executing `man -d git-log` and `man -d -c git-log` and comparing the output. I see that the differences are mainly about missing debug output of the following kind in the case when I run `man -d -c git-log` (i.e. in the good case):

```
update_directory_cache /usr/share/man/cat3curses: miss
can't open directory /usr/share/man/cat3curses: No such file or directory
directory cache update failed
```

Though, in both cases there are lines as follows:

```
update_directory_cache /usr/share/man/man3curses: miss
can't open directory /usr/share/man/man3curses: No such file or directory
directory cache update failed
```

Comment: The issue is due to the way your distribution wraps `man` to display all choices for matching man pages (either with the `whatis` command or a slightly modified format -- try it `whatis git-log`). How you change the default handling will also be distribution specific. Check the environment variables specified in `man 1 man` (at the end) on  your system.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't understand what I can do to overcome this. I have not found any suitable option/variable in `man 1 man`. The output of  `whatis git-log` is as follows: `git-log (1)          - Show commit logs`. Also I see that `man -w git-log` shows only `/app/vbuild/SLED11-x86_64/git/2.14.1/man/man1/git-log.1` which seems to be ok but when I run `man git-log` I still have to choose between 1 and 1+ sections (though, it looks like it is not really possible to choose 1+).

Comment: `SLED11`, is that SuSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11? SuSE has always had a reasonable wrapper for `man`. If that is your desktop, then I'm pretty sure the behavior is controlled via `/etc/manpath.config`. Check under `SECTIONS` at the end of that file if you have it. See if there is a `1+` entry. You may be able to disable display there. I haven't messed with SLED, but have use 7.0(Air) through Leap. My only other though would be a file in `/etc/sysconfig`, but I don't see anything `man` related in there. You should be able to chose `1+` by typing `1+` when it is displayed.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be SuSE and it is a server where I log in as an ordinary user to do my daily work. There is no 1+ in `/etc/manpath.config`. I tried to set local (empty) config file with man's option `-C` but this does not help. I cannot choose section 1+ when asked or at least it has no visible effect (entering any characters results in that the page `GIT-LOG(1)` is shown).